# Age Calculation Error

Tags: java

When I run this code it says no main program found, because I am missing 
    public static void main(String []args but It will not let me use both of these. How do I correct this issue?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Week6Methods4 {

    public int getAge(int year, int month, int day) {
        Date now = new Date();
        int nowMonth = now.setMonth() + 1;
        int nowYear = now.setYear() + 1900;
        int result = nowYear - year;

        if (month > nowMonth) {
            result--;
        } else if (month == nowMonth) {
            int nowDay = now.getDate();

            if (day > nowDay) {
                result--;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter Date of Birth");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int DOB = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us all of your code, and please indent properly.

Comment: Add a `public static void main(String... args)` method to your program, see [A Closer Look at the "Hello World!" Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) for some ideas...

Comment: What do you mean "it will not let me use both of these"?  Your program needs a `public static void main()`.  If there's an error when you try to add one, show that code and that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few hints for helping you**

**First**, Functions that you used from Date class are deprecated

> **1**. getMonth()
>
> **2**. getYear()

[Take a look at this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#getDate())

**Second**, you must define your method `getAge` out of the main method.

**why?**

because `getAge` is separate method and unique  like main method

Use this as a **blue print**

```
public class Sample {

public void A() {
  ...
  your code
  ...
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ...
   your code
   ...
  }
}
```

---

**In your new post, you for got to add proper import for Data class**

add this to your import

```
import java.util.Date;
```

and instead of setters you have to use getters

```
    int nowMonth = now.setMonth() + 1;
    int nowYear = now.setYear() + 1900;
```

change them to `now.getMonth()` and `now.getYear()`

Comment: I tried to implement what you said but it still does not work, I do not think I am fully grasping this. Now it says in the statement Date now = new Date(); cannot find symbol

Comment: @guinea2 did you update your post with the new code that is troubling you?

Comment: Yes I did the code there now is the new one, I really appreciate you helping me. I am struggling with java

Comment: where is public class part?

Comment: did you see after your imports what it is missing ?